# Column Index not finding a column that definitely exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
try {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select time from updateTimes where type = 'root'", null);
    long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("time"));
} catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

}
```

This exception gets thrown, even though the column "time" definitely exists, the the same query returns data as expected when using the sqlite3 client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The cursor is not at a valid index.  You need to move it first:

```
if (c.moveToNext()) {
    time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("time"));
}
```